# Display of different pins custom on map SwiftUi (error extra argument)

Tags: swift, swiftui, arguments, extra

I'm trying to display custom pins on my map, only an error appears "extra arguments at postions #7, #8 in call. If anyone can help me I would be grateful!
(I'm new to swift)

```
var body: some View {
   
    VStack {
    if locationManager.location != nil {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region, interactionModes: .all,  showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: nil, annotationItems: pins,
            annotationContent: { pin in
                MapAnnotation(coordinate: pin.coordinate,
                              content: {
                                PinButtonView(pin: pin)
                              })

            }, annotationItems: pins2,
            annotationContent: { pin in
                MapAnnotation(coordinate: pin.coordinate,
                              content: {
                    PinButtonView2(pin2: pin)
                              })
            }).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    } else {
        Text("On te localise BG... attend 2s")
    }
    }
        .onAppear {
            setCurrentLocation()
        }
    
}
```

}

Comment: That is because you can only have one `annotationItems` and one `annotationContent`, and you are attempting to have two. The compiler is expecting 6 arguments total, and you have 8. You can put some logic in your `PinButtonView` to return different pins depending upon the annotation that is sent in. It is hard to determine what you want to have, except for different pins.

Comment: Thank you very much, I feel stupid... Thank you for taking the time to answer!

Comment: We have ALL been there.